# fstream error, "streambuf" when I try to compile and run

Tags: c++

```
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
```

> ```
> Here's a youtube link to explain myself on what errors I'm getting.
> ```
>
> I don't understand why the "fstream" object isn't working correctly. I declare it, then I try to open the file with the full path directory in the argument. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mNm_OwVLR5g

[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mNm_OwVLR5g&feature=youtu.be)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    ifstream myfile; 

    ofstream pot
    pot.open("accept.txt");

    char status, answer;
    string fname, lname, phone, address;
    float rate;

    myfile.open("/Users/Lois/Documents/Xcode/lab_6/potentials.txt");

    myfile >> status;
    myfile >> fname;
    myfile >> lname;
    myfile >> phone;


    if (status == 'x' || status == 'X') {
        rate = 7.9;
    }

    else {
        rate = 12.9;
    }

    cout << "Name: " << lname << ", " << fname << endl;
    cout << "Phone: " << phone << "\nRate: " << rate << endl;


    cout << "Did the Customer accept the card offer?\nEnter 'A' for Yes or 'D' for No.\n";
    cin >> answer;
    cin.ignore();

    if (answer == 'A' || answer == 'a') {
        cout << "Enter Customers Address: \n";
        getline(cin, address);
        cout << "Thank you for taking the time to listen to and accept our offer! \n";
    }

    else if (answer == 'D' || answer == 'd') {
        if (rate = 7.9) {
            cout << "Are you certain? We offer cash back rewards.\n";
            cout << "I can give you a special number to call for a better card. \n";
        }
        else
            cout << "Thank you for your time today " << fname << "." << endl;

    }
    else
        cout << "Please enter an appropriate response. \n";

    pot << status;
    pot << " ";
    pot << fname;
    pot << " ";
    pot << lname;
    pot << " ";
    pot << address;
    pot << endl;
    pot.close();

    cout << rate << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "ofstream pot" now reads  "ofstream pot;" still the same error though

Comment: Another video showing you everything I'm seeing. I hope it helps to troubleshoot.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QG3bEUL9fO0&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Your formatting is all over the place, and what is the relevance of a `<script>` tag? Furthermore, the content of your question shall not be a YouTube link; this is not your personal "troubleshooting" service; it is a Q&A of questions about programming languages. No idea what you're doing here.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didnt mean to add the script thing up there... I kept getting an error message about formatting when I tried to post the code... so I followed the 'advanced help' thing and it said use google beautify... whose instructions said put that in the code block thingy. I'm still new to the site and am unfamiliar with the user interface mistakenly put it in the wrong place...

As for personal troubleshooting service? I thought the purpose of this site was for programming to help each other learn... am I mistaken...?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Xcode but your program compiles correctly with GCC with the semicolon (well there's also the issue with `if (rate = 7.9)` but that's another story), if the code you've posted above is exactly the same as what you're compiling then my only guess is you didn't save the changes after adding the semicolon.

Comment: @user657267 Thank you for your help. The program WASSSSSSSS working correctly until I tried to FIX THAT VERY ISSUE/BUG. 

LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm a college student. When I google errors to find answers stackoverflow is often one of the highest ranked responses. So stackoverflow is not designed for people to learn about coding? I'm confused as to what you mean when you're asking what I'm doing here...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: @user657267 The  **(rate = 7.9)** was a **(rate == 7.9)** but when I tested the program and entered d, to test the code, the program simply did not execute the next if statement, **"cout << "Are you certain..." "**

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Also, I made the youtube videos because frankly, I think it helps to **clarify** the problem at hand **much** better. I can't count the number of times I've found myself on this website reading through the comments and questions to find that many times the people posting don't articulate themselves well, and the responders are confused as to what's being asked. I felt like it was just another tool that helped...?

Comment: @user657267 I can assure you I saved before attempting to compile... lol =).

Comment: @Primetime You were mistaken. This is a Q&A format. We write questions in text, and answers in text, occasionally with image illustrations and URL references. But the format does not include "the context is explained in this YouTube video". And if someone hasn't written their question properly, that means they need to improve the question, not transform it into a YouTube video. Perhaps you mistook SO for a helpdesk? Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
I'm posting this answer for those who might one day come across the same problem I did. 
The error was not with the code, other than the missing ";" which user657267 pointed out.
```

After consulting another community `CS50` on `Facebook` I discovered that when compiled using `clang` in the terminal window, the program compiled and ran error free. I tried reading through the Q&A of stack overflow extensively, looking at guidelines to posting a good question, and `help center`about asking. There I found that topics allowed included `software tools` commonly used by programmers.

In this case, I discovered that Xcode was **buggy** for me. I'm not sure what type of bug. But there were discussions of binary and etc in the Facebook Group which was far over my head.

I have to ask another question now....

I don't like speaking in absolutes but will every

> **IDE** Integrated Developer Environment(for future googlers)

I encounter in my career become buggy after a few years? Would the best way to avoid encountering errors like this which give me hours of BS to be to write code from the command line? I'm sorry if this is an opinion or subjective question, but what other way is there to ask the question. I'm learning how to write programs and one of the **most prominent** ways I'm spending my time is debugging issues I encounter because of the way in which my IDE was programmed. How the compiler writes binary, where the IDE has defaulted to save files it writes, etc.